# Reading STRING, INTEGER in the same line with Pascal

Tags: pascal

How do i read in pascal a string and an integer in the same line like the C's scanf("%s %d", str, &n); version?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but I am pretty sure there is no way. You must read them separated.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal does not have an equivilent of C's `...scanf()` functions.  You will have to either find a third-party implementation, write your own implementation, or just parse the string directly.

Comment: Which Pascal are you talking about ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If from stdin:

```
  read(s); read(i);
```

If not, then you are out of luck for Borland's Pascal variants. Free Pascal (2.4+) inherited a [variant](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readstr.html)
 from Apple(Standard Pascal derivative) variants that takes input from a string:

```
 readstr(inputstr,s,i);
```

IIRC this is an Extended Pascal standard procedure that is commonly implemented by standard Pascal variants too, since it is basically a variant of the standard Pascal readln from input.